# Why is Livewire creating an empty object when an event is fired?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

This is a follow-up to this question [How does Laravel-Livewire fires events and listens to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616842/how-does-laravel-livewire-fires-events-and-listens-to-them) answered by [@Qirel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535200/qirel).

Basically, I have a livewire component that fires an event after a user selects a radio box option. I now understand that the events fired by livewire are executed after all the PHP is done. Now, the problem is this:

I have an object called **`Formulary`**, that belongs to a **`Test`** and I use that relationship to bring the **`Questionnaire`**

This is the relationship between a **`Test`** and a **`Questionnaire`**:

```
/**
 * A test belongs to a questionnaire
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function questionnaire()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Questionnaire::class );
}
```

And this is how I create the relationship between a **`Formulary`** and a **`Questionnaire`** in the **`Formulary`** class:

```
/**
 * A formulary belongs to a test
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function test()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Test::class );
}

/**
 * A formulary answers a questionnaire
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function questionnaire()
{
    if( $this->test != null ){
        return $this->test->questionnaire();
    }
    dd( $this );
}
```

I left the **`dd( $this )`** in the `questionnaire()` method just for testing purposes.

When the user choses the radio box in a livewire component called **`DisplayRow`**, it fires an event

```
/**
 * Sets the answer and fires the event to update the parent view
 */
public function setAnswer()
{
    FormularyUpdated::dispatch( $this->formulary, $this->question, $this->answer );
    $this->emitUp( 'formularyUpdated', $this->formulary->id );
}
```

So, the user fired the event and I have another component called **`DisplaySection`** with a listener to `'formularyUpdated'`:

```
protected $listeners = [
    'sectionAdvanced',
    'formularyUpdated',
];

/**
 *
 */
public function formularyUpdated( Formulary $formulary )
{
    dd( 'Here first' );
    dd( $formulary );
}
```

After the user clicks the checkbox, I expected to die and dump the `'Here first'` message and if I removed that `dd( 'Here first' )`, I should see the full information from the **`Formulary`** object, but what I got instead was the `dd( $this )` in the **`Formulary`** class in the `questionnaire()` method. Meaning the **`Test`** is null, but not just the test, the **`Formulary`** object is totally empty and without attributes. No idea what is going on.

[image: This is the ER Diagram of the tests table]

In my software a client (**`Person`**), wants to apply a **`Questionnaire`** to its employees (**`Person`**). So he buys a **`Test`**, and each **`Formulary`** is the answer that each employee gives to the **`Test`**

This is where I call the `$formulary->questionnaire`, this is the view of the **`DisplaySection`** component:

```
<div class="letter mx-auto" id="section-holder">
    <div class="paper-title d-flex justify-content-between">
        @foreach($formulary->questionnaire->getData( 'logos', [] ) as $logo)
            <img src="{{ asset($logo[ 'path' ]) }}" class="img-fluid h-100" />
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="section-questions">
        @foreach($section->questions as $question)
            <livewire:formularies.edit.display-row :question="$question->id"
                                                   :formulary="$formulary->id" :wire:key="$question->id" />
            <hr />
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like the `questionare()`  relation should be a `hasOneThrough` instead, so you can do `public function questionnaire() { return $this->hasOneThrough(Questionnaire::class, Test::class); }`. It would be interesting to see, where you're calling `$formulary->questionnaire()`, what is `$formulary->test`?

Comment: I have edited the question with the ER diagram and the code of the view of DisplaySection